# why not implement c++ std::vector::pop_front() by shifting the pointer to vector[0]?

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, vector

Why can't `pop_front()` be implemented for C++ vectors by simply shifting the pointer contained in the vector's name one spot over?  So in a vector containing an array `foo`, `foo` is a pointer to `foo[0]`, so `pop_front()` would make the pointer `foo = foo[1]` and the bracket operator would just do the normal pointer math. Is this something to do with how C++ keeps track of the memory you're using for what when it allocates space for an array?

This is similar to other questions I've seen about why `std::vector` doesn't have a `pop_front()` function, I will admit, but i haven't anyone asking about why you can't shift the pointer.

Comment: You can use `deque` as a more general and flexible container essentially as a drop-in replacement for `vector`. Some might even say that `deque` should be the "default" container in C++, and `vector` should be reserved for the special need of contiguous storage.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Isn't `deque` a doubly-linked list? If so, it should by no means be the default container.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: The emphasis is on "if so". Luckily, we are in the "else" branch here :-)

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: No it is not. If that were the case, we wouldn't have `deque` because `std::list<>` is already doubly linked.

Comment: Clarification to my earlier comment: Doubly-linked List may be used for the queue itself but the whole container cannot be a doubly-linked list because then it won't support constant time element access. And +1 to OP for a good question!

Comment: i'm mainly using vector because i wanted access to an arbitrary element without linear access time.  that is a good thing to consider, and i changed how my code worked anyhow, so a list or deque would probably be a better choice now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `vector` wouldn't be able to free its memory if it did this.

Generally, you want the overhead per `vector` object to be small. That means you only store three items: the pointer to the first element, the capacity, and the length.

In order to implement what you suggest, every `vector` ever (**all** of them) would need an additional member variable: the offset from the start pointer at which the zeroth element resides. Otherwise, the memory could not be freed, since the original handle to it would have been lost.

It's a tradeoff, but generally the memory consumption of an object which may have millions of instances is more valuable than the corner case of doing *the absolute worst thing you can do performance-wise* to the `vector`.

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what i was looking for.  is there no way to call delete/free on only the memory you're leaving out?  for example, you store the pointer to element 1 in a temporary variable, shift the vector's pointer to element 2 and then delete element 1?  i know delete definitely distinguishes between a single element and a block (`delete [] array`), though this is for dynamic memory.

Comment: @IanOoi That allocation strategy would be really inefficient. In order to be freed individually, allocations must be *tracked* individually - the bookkeeping overhead, both in terms of wasted RAM and in terms of time for new allocations, would get bad very quickly.

Answer (score 3):

Because implementers want to optimize the size of a vector. They usually use 3 pointers, one for the beginning, one for the capacity (the allocated end) and one for the end.

Doing what you require adds another 4 bytes to every vector (and there are a lot of those in a c++ program) for very little benefit: the contract of vector is to be fast when pushing back new elements, removing and inserting are "unsual" operations and their performance matter less than the size of the class.

Comment: I don't understand what justifies your hard claim that "performance matter less than the size". Without saying for who and how often it matters less, your statement is pointless at best.

Comment: The standard imposes performance constraints on `push_back` and `[]` only. The two implementations I know (MSVC / GCC) use 3 pointers because _they_ think that's size matters more than performance on other operation, I merely repeat what I've been reading online (though I admit I won't be able to find the sources easily, I remember a video on C9 by Stephan T. Lavavej that mentionned it at least). Now, of course, some people may care about "front" operations more than others, but the standard guys think it was not worth covering in vector. There are other classes for that. Other answers agree.

Comment: the main issue i have with this is that my suggestion shouldn't add another pointer's worth of bytes to the vector, unless (as i commented on Borealid's answer) there is no other way to free the memory, in which case the real reason is because there's no other way make sure the memory gets freed.  i was mainly suggesting you shift that first pointer to point at a new "head" for the vector, hopefully freeing the old head in the process.    this helped me see more of how vectors are implemented though, so thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I started typing out an elaborate answer explaining how the memory is allocated and freed but after typing it all out I realized that memory issues alone don't justify why `pop_front` isn't there as other answers here suggested.

Having `pop_front` in a vector where the extra cost is another pointer is justifiable in most circumstances. The problem, in my opinion, is `push_front`. If the container has `pop_front` then it should also have `push_front` otherwise the container is not being consistent. `push_front` is definitely expensive for a vector container (unless you match your `push`es with your `pop`s which is not a good design). Without `push_front` the vector is *really* wasting memory if one does lots of `pop_front` operations with no `push_front` functionality.

Now the need for `pop_front` and `push_front` is there for a container that is similar to a vector (constant time random access) which is why there is [`deque`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/deque/).

Comment: ok, i was talking with my roommate about how pop_front should work (and it shouldn't be an extra pointer because of how arrays are implemented) and how push_front wouldn't because you COULD use a similar scheme as the pop_front but there's no way to verify the extra slot(s) you're adding will be free and not allocated to something else without doing a lot of magic.  this makes sense, but it still seems a little strange.

also deque is constant random access?  mind is blown.  i will look into this.

Comment: @IanOoi: "i was talking with my roommate about how pop_front should work (and it shouldn't be an extra pointer because of how arrays are implemented)" You cannot free the contiguously allocated memory unless you call `free()` on the original memory address, which you are losing by moving the pointer. In short, you _will_ require an extra pointer to keep track of the original memory address (or a variable that stores how many times `pop_front()` was called which takes the same amount of memory as a pointer on 32 bit systems).

Answer (score 1):

You could, but it would complicate the implementation a bit, and add a pointer of overhead to the type's size (so it could track the actual allocation's address). Is that worth it? Sometimes. First consider other structures which may handle your usage better (maybe deque?).

Answer (score 1):

You *could* do that, but `vector` is designed to be a simple container with constant time index lookups and push/pop from the end. Doing what you suggest would complicate the implementation as it would have to track the allocated beginning and the "current" beginning. Not to mention that you still couldn't guarantee constant time insertion at the front but you might get it sometimes.

If you need a container with constant time front and back insertion and removal, that's precisely what `deque` is for, there's no need to modify `vector` to handle it.

Comment: it's mainly a curiosity, since vectors are built around arrays (correct me if i'm mistaken) and you COULD still guarantee constant time _removal_ if not insertion, which was what i was mainly asking.  i said it in another comment that even if you did the pointer finagling i don't think push_front would be guaranteed to even be possible if the block right "before" the vector is allocated to something else already, meaning that you'd either have to do the silly shift everything way or give up.  the consistency would still be a problem having a pop_front but no push_front.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::deque` instead of `std::vector`. It's a double-ended-queue with also the vector-like access members. It implements both front and back push/pop.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/deque/

Answer (score 0):

Another shortcoming of your suggestion is that you'll waste memory spaces as you can't make use of those on the left of the array after shifting. The more you execute `pop_front()`, the more you'll waste until the vector is destructed.

Comment: One could imagine that a later resize might make use of that space.

Comment: this is a really good point, and i think Borealid is right that if someone did such an implementation, it's unsure if the destructor COULD free the memory at all since you've left out chunks of data which have no pointers and which can't be freed.  you could try having it where you shift the name to point to the next index and call delete/free on the single space instead of the whole block, but that might make it angry still.